# Angular Material 6 - How to programmatically set mat-paginator offset?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using `MatPaginator` from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview), just trying to update the offset text on the paginator in a callback or whichever might be recommended way. Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jlrrveagyva?file=app%2Fpaginator-configurable-example.ts) they have up.

I'm making a request, getting the resp with offset. Setting the `paginator.pageIndex`, perhaps it's the correct page but the range text is showing as if were the [first page](http://prntscr.com/kfu51m). So I just need access to a method that updates the text as [expected](http://prntscr.com/kfu79y).

The [API docs](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) say:

> To modify the labels and text displayed, create a new instance of MatPaginatorIntl and include it in a custom provider

Has anyone seen examples of `MatPaginatorIntl` being used? Just looking for a little jump start.

Comment: You try to update what into what?

Comment: @Antoniossss the text in the paginator that says `11-1000`, whatever the numbers add up to for the offset.